# Send current windows user info to rest api from nodejs client

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, authentication

I have a rest API which uses windows authentication.How can I call windows authenticate rest API from node js

in angular js, I can pass current windows user parameter to API use these commands.

> $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
>
> $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;

Comment: Just to clarify since you are mixing front and backend technologies in your question.  You are calling the API from an application written with Node.JS on the server side?

Comment: I have a asp.net web api with windows authentication (Server),and I have a nodejs client